# How to claim past experience for a startup portfolio?

Tags: professionalism, communication, work-experience, startup, portfolio

I am working on my startup becoming self-employed and I have a page on my site that I would like to display my experience. The problem is, I did not get this experience with my start-up, but with past employers.

Is it ok to list past experience if I don't claim it as a "portfolio" of sorts from my start-up, rather, just as "past experience" in a list of domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely Ok.

You can bring it up as:

> Implementing hands on experience with technology X gained from Y years in the Z field.

Also maybe:

> Covering core technologies such as:
>
> - Tech X
> - Tech Y
>
> Specialized in:
>
> - Tech Z

Good luck!